# xcode 6 simulator app Documents folder is inconsistent is there a fix?

Tags: ios, xcode6

I have noticed a big issues with xcode 6. The app data folder keeps switching and there are usually a couple of copies out there. I don't really know why xcode is doing this but it's very troublesome. The big issue is that when I start the app sometimes it looks at one folder and sometimes another, if I had saved some data in the data folder, sometimes the data is inconsistent between the two.

I use the SimPholders2 App to find these folders. Which was quite a challenge already.
So the question is, is there a safe and secure way to save the data in the simulator to make sure that it stays consistent?

Comment: starting with xcode 6 it is simulating devices.. so every device has its own folder. theoretically you can access one global folder from within your app ... check if you are in simulator and when you are access a folder anywhere on your mac. the simulator is not sandboxed.

Comment: Wait? Really? I thought it was? So I can access my HD from the simulator?

Comment: yes .. should be possible .. I've not done it with xcode 6 but I don't think it changed.

Comment: When you build and run it will grab everything you have in your document folder and move it to the new one. There is no inconsistency.

Comment: Hi Viktor, I do have inconsistencies. I don't know why but I do. If you look at the folder it also doesn't refresh in Finder immediately, you have to force refresh by doing some changes to the folder. It's not clear what happens when the app is open and you save stuff.

Comment: I usually open documents folder in Finder and once I rebuild the app it will autoswitch into correct folder along with all stuff I had in the previous one.

Comment: Mmm. I do the same but if I am saving something in the app and looking at that folder, it won't always appear. It's really not clear in which folder it saves it. My case is that I have a local JSON database. I save to that database and then next time I build those changes are not there, because the path of the build changed. It seems that xcode keeps at least 2 sometimes more.

Comment: I've just tried to manually copy random .jpeg into Documents and after rebuild it moved everything to the different folder along with that .jpeg. I am afraid I cannot help you:(

Comment: Thanks Victor. I will do some tests to build a replicable case then post it on here.